# Kubernetes deployment using shared-disk FC HBA options

Tags: kubernetes, san

I have been looking at available Kubernetes storage add-ons and have been unable to put together something that would work with our setup. Current situation is several nodes each with an FC HBA controller connected to a single LUN. I realize that some sort of cluster FS will need to be implemented, but once that is in place I don't see how I would then connect this to Kubernetes.

We've discussed taking what we have and making an iSCSI or NFS host but in addition to requiring another dedicated machine, we lose all the advantages of having the storage directly available on each node. Is there any way to make use of our current infrastructure?

Details:
4x Kubernetes nodes (1 master) deployed via kubeadm on Ubuntu 16.04 using flannel as the network addon, each system has the SAN available as block device (/dev/sdb)